# Converting a child class to its generic grandparent

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I have found my self in a situation where I need to provide functionality to perform the same tasks with about a dozen different, but very similar objects all of which map to different tables in our database. So I figured it would be a good opportunity to go all out with inheritance and generics.

I have run into an issue where I have a `Grandparent`->`Parent`->`Child` relationship and I need to be able to pass the `Child` to a function that expects a `Grandparent`, which would work just fine if it weren't for my use of generics. The error I get is:

> Arguement type '`ChildA`' is not assignable to parameter type '`GrandparentA<ParentB,ParentC>`'

Below is a very simplified version of what I am attempting, but it still throws the same error:

```
void Main()
{
    var child = new ChildA();

    DoSomething(child);
}

public void DoSomething(GrandParentA<ParentB, ParentC> Data) { }

public abstract class GrandParentA<T1, T2> 
    where T1 : ParentB
    where T2 : ParentC
{
    public abstract T1 Foo { get; set; }
    public abstract T2 Bar { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ParentA<T> : GrandParentA<ChildB, T>
    where T : ParentC
{
    public override abstract ChildB Foo { get; set; }
    public override abstract T Bar { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : ParentA<ChildC> 
{ 
    public override ChildB Foo { get; set; }
    public override ChildC Bar { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ParentB { }

public class ChildB : ParentB { }

public abstract class ParentC { }

public class ChildC : ParentC { }
```

The compiler error thrown with the call to `DoSomething(child)`, which I would have thought would work because everything about the `child` can be upcast to what its grandparent has, there is no downcasting to confuse things (I think I got the up/down the right way round!?) Where am I going wrong?

Comment: please read this: http://www.its-not-its.info/ . Hopefully, you'll revert back to my edit then :) Also, "Grandparent->Child" is not a piece of code, so shouldn't be marked as such. And, finally, I completely don't understand why you don't want to use quotation markdown for error messages (which also are not code).

Comment: It wasn't so much that bit I took issue with but the "correction" of the error message to omit the `<ParentB,ParentC>` part (thus making it incorrect) and the edit it at the end to make it more polite.

Comment: Classes are invariant - you could add an interface and make `T1` and `T2` covariant but you'd also need to remove the setters for the `Foo` and `Bar` properties.

Comment: @Ben I understand. Sorry for my mistake - I know how to fix it. As for the politeness, please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions . I've fix the edit, hopefully it's fine now. Please don't revert if I've made some minor mistakes - fix them instead, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are invariant, so `GrandParentA<ParentB, ParentC>` is not assignable from `GrandParentA<ChildB, ChildC>`. Thus you have to make `DoSomething` method to be generic, so it can accept `GrandParentA` with any generic parameters:

```
public void DoSomething<T1, T2>(GrandParentA<T1, T2> Data)
    where T1 : ParentB
    where T2 : ParentC
```

Comment: As a follow up, do you know if it's possible to use a generic (e.g. GrandParentA) as the model in an MVC view? You can't seem to do it like this: `@model GrandParentA<T1, T2> where T1 : ParentB where T2 : ParentC`

Comment: @Ben I does not have experience with MVC, so can not answer this.

Comment: No worries! I will ask it as a new question. You answer helped me a lot anyway